# Как получить все значения произвольного поля для текущей выборки товаров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть ИМ с вот таким фильтром:

[image: Общий вид фильтра]

"Коллекция" - это произвольное поле для товара. Допустим, я нахожусь в категории "Платья". Нужно чтобы слева выводились только те значения произвольного поля, которые есть у товаров, в текущей выборке ( я имею ввиду те, что сейчас выбраны на данной странице категории и далее по пагинации).

Чтобы не было такого, что выводится "осень", хотя в данной категории ни у одного товара данной выборки такого значения поля нету...

Comment: На вопрос пока никто не ответил, потому что непонятно, чем сделан фильтр и какой код выводит "коллекцию".

Comment: Не важно а сделан фильтр и как выводить коллекцию. Это я знаю как сделать. Вопрос в том, как получить значения поля коллекция для текущей выборки... Дальше уже отсортировать массив данных и фильтровать выборку не является проблемой

Comment: ну раз вы все знаете, используйте get_post_meta()

Comment: Вы не читаете вопрос. Вопрос в том, как получить данные о том, какие посты сейчас в выборке. Перебрать в еще одном цикле и охранять айди в массив выглядит не очень оптимизировано...

Comment: Так а встрять в текущую выборку никак нельзя, чтобы собирать данные о полях?

Answer (score 0):

Прописав get_post_meta( ID ); получим все метаполя.

https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_meta

> Использование
>
> $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, [$key, [$single]] );
> $post_id(число) (обязательный)
> ID поста, произвольные поля которого нужно получить.
> По умолчанию: нет
> $key(строка)
> Название произвольного поля, значение которого нужно получить. **Если оставить поле пустым, будут получены все произвольные поля поста**.
> По умолчанию: ''
> $single(логический)
> true - вернет значение метаполя (если полей несколько то вернет значение первого метаполя).
> false - вернет массив всех значений мета полей с указанным ключом.
>
> Если в значении произвольного поля находится сериализованный массив, то значение true вернет, нормальный массив, а если указать false, то вернется массив в элементе "[0]" которого будет все тот же сериализованный массив.
> По умолчанию: false

Соответственно прогоном всех товаров на данной странице и получая все метаполя каждого, методом перебора всех полей каждого, находим какие у него имеются значения, добавляем в выборку, если ещё не добавлены. Затем по выборке выводим только те, что встречались.

Comment: Увы, это не то, что я спрашивал. Как получить поля и как их обработать для каждого поста понятно. Как получить данные о том, какие посты в текущей выборке без перебора их в основном цикле

Comment: Ну если уж речь о получении без перебора get_metadata возвращает только внутри цикла, без перебора есть вариант выполнить свой запрос вида $ids = implode(',', $products_ids); "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id`IN ({$ids}) AND `meta_value`<>0" и настроить под себя критерии поиска или перебирать уже по полученным значениям, поскольку насколько я понимаю, весь список функций работы с метаполями https://wp-kama.ru/function-cat/metadannye подразумевает их перебор в цикле перебора постов.

Comment: Либо же посмотрите на WP_Meta_Query https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_meta_query
дополнение к WP_Query можно получать сразу посты, если работает по принципу постов но для полей - то что вам надо, если нет, то только самому )